# How to get the field name in form

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I have a form, containing different fields(firstname, lastname).

For those,I have defined like

```
<table>
   <tr>
        <td>
             FirstName:
        </td>         
        <td>
             <input type="text" id="fn" data-bind="value:fn" name="fn" data-type="string"  maxlength="45" />
             <span data-for="fn" class="k-invalid-msg"></span>
        </td>
        <td>
             LastName: 
        </td>        
        <td>
             <input type="text" id="ln" data-bind="value:ln" name="ln" data-type="string" maxlength="45"/>
             <span data-for="ln" class="k-invalid-msg"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
             <a href ="#"><span></span><input type="button" id ="search" value="Search" /></a> 
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What I want is that, when user enters a value at any field in text box, I want to retrieve the "td" field in which user has entered the value(firstname or lastname).

How to get that field value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you require:

```
$('input').change(function() {
    var label = $(this).parent().prev().text();
    alert(label);
});​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NUBM2/

Comment: But perhaps this maybe not the idea way to do your ultimate requirement. I can suggest better ways if you can give some context

Comment: hi janith,If I have drop down then how can I get the dropdown serach field

Comment: In that case you will be using `<select>` tags. You can modify the above jQuery selector as: `$('select, input')`